# How to return individual months within a range of dates

Tags: mysql, join, cross-join

What I'm trying to do is:

QUERY ONE looks like this;

```
    SELECT ws.asset_id,ws.user_ts AS myFrom ,os.user_ts AS myTo 
    FROM wsdays ws LEFT 
    JOIN ( 
    SELECT MAX(c.user_ts)user_ts,os.asset_id 
    FROM onsite os 
    JOIN cashup c ON c.onsite_id=os.onsite_id GROUP BY asset_id)os ON
    ws.asset_id=os.asset_id,( 
    SELECT @sDate,@eDate)dum 
    WHERE (ws.asset_id=28 OR ws.asset_id=68)
```

QUERY ONE RESULTS

```
    +----------+----------+----------+
    | asset_id |myFrom    | myTo     |
    +----------+----------+----------+
    | 1        |15/01/01  |15/01/04  |
    +----------+----------+----------+
    | 2        |15/03/16  |15/03/20  |
    +----------+----------+----------+
```

QUERY TWO looks like this;

```
    SELECT @day:=DATE_FORMAT((@sDate+ INTERVAL a.i*10000 + b.i*1000 +c.i*100+ d.i*10 + e.i DAY),'%Y/%m/%d') date 
    FROM ints a 
    JOIN ints b 
    JOIN ints c 
    JOIN ints d 
    JOIN ints e,( 
    SELECT @sd:=myDate('2015-01-01 12:00:00'),@myWeek:=0,@sDate:='2015-01-01 12:00:00',@eDate:='2015-03-30 13:30:00') AS dummy 
    WHERE (a.i*10000 + b.i*1000 + c.i*100 + d.i*10 + e.i<=DATEDIFF(@eDate,@sDate) 
    ORDER BY 1
```

QUERY TWO RESULTS

```
    +-----------+
    |  date     |
    +-----------+
    |  15/01/01 |
    +-----------+
    |  15/01/02 |
    +-----------+
    |  ........ |
    +-----------+
    |  15/03/29 |
    +-----------+
    |  15/03/30 |
    +-----------+
```

I have tried a couple of joins but none give me the result wanted (hence my post). How do I join these so the final query gives me this result:

```
    +-----------+-----------+
    | asseti_id |  date     |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |   1       |  15/01/01 |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |   1       |  15/01/02 |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |   1       |  15/01/03 |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |   1       |  15/01/04 |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |   1       |  15/03/16 |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |   2       |  15/03/17 |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |   2       |  15/03/18 |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |   2       |  15/03/19 |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |   2       |  15/03/20 |
    +-----------+-----------+
    |   2       |  15/03/21 |
    +-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing. In other words, please post the code that you have tried.

Comment: Proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) would probably help too!

Comment: Mattia  and Gunr2171 thxs for the feed back; I have tried to put a synopsis of the code above and hope that helps any further suggestions will be helpful. But I am  interested in the theory of joining TWO tables into one with the above results. THANKS again

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT id, min(date) as from, max(date) as to
FROM cal
GROUP BY id
```